# TypeScript : blank JSON response

Tags: typescript

I am getting blank json from below code.

The class declaration is as:

```
export class Account {

public amount: string;
public name: string;

constructor(amount: string, name: string) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.name = name;

   }
}

let account: Account[] =[];

function accountList () {
    client.getAccounts({}, function (err, accounts) {
        accounts.forEach(function (acct) {
            console.log('my bal: ' + acct.balance.amount + ' for ' + acct.name);
            account.push(new Account(acct.balance.amount, acct.name));
        });
        return account;
    })
};
```

I am calling the function using,

```
app.get('/accounts', (req, res) =>
    res.send(JSON.stringify(accountList())));
```

Please suggest what wrong is done here.

Comment: Why you use `this.account`, account is just a let variable?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: @NikolaAndreev, removed "this" keyword, however the JSON response is blank.

Comment: are you sure acct.balance is never null ? are you sure that acct.balance.amount returned by client.getAccount() is always a string ? And as already asked, **what is the exception message** ? Or other error ?

Comment: also, if this is Typescript then I recommend to indicate the type of the argument acct of your anonymous callback function in the forEach. (though it probably won't fix your issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is explained in the comments below (hopefully). This is a common problem, but tricky to explain.

```
function accountList () {
    // (1) Asynchronously get accounts, AFTER which our function `function (err, accounts)` will be called
    client.getAccounts({}, function (err, accounts) {
        // (3) when the async call has completed, we run this inner function
        // but accountList already returned void - see (2) below
        accounts.forEach(function (acct) {
            console.log('my bal: ' + acct.balance.amount + ' for ' + acct.name);
            account.push(new Account(acct.balance.amount, acct.name));
        });
        return account;
    })

    // (2) the accountList method returns
};
```

You can solve this by accepting a callback into `accountList` - which you call instead of the line `return account;` OR you can return a Promise from `accountList` and perform your JSON serialization in the `then`.

## Promise Version

Here is an example using a promise:

```
function accountList(): Promise<Account[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.getAccounts({}, function (err, accounts) {
            let account: Account[] = [];

            accounts.forEach(function (acct) {
                console.log('my bal: ' + acct.balance.amount + ' for ' + acct.name);
                account.push(new Account(acct.balance.amount, acct.name));
            });

            resolve(account);
        });
    });
}
```

And your calling code:

```
app.get('/accounts', (req, res) => {
    accountList().then((accounts) => {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(accounts));
    });
});
```